# Separar primer nombre listas python

Tags: python

Buenas tardes esa es mi duda por ejemplo tengo la lista:

```
estudaintes= ['Mario Miguel Diaz', 'Luis Javier Alvarado', 'Juan de Cárdenas',
              'Pedro Jesus Hernandez', 'Jose de Miranda', 'Juan de Salcedo']
```

y quisiera extraer solo el primer nombre. osea:

```
list = ['Mario ','Luis','Juan', ...]
```

he intentado el metodo `split()` pero no funciona con listas. Agradeceria si alguien pudiera iluminarme en ese problemas gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usando comprensión de listas:

```
lista = [x.split()[0] for x in estudaintes]
```

aparte de split, fijate que se selecciona el primer elemento con `[0]`.

> siempre y cuando no sea un nombre chino que tenga el primer nombre al final

Answer (score 0):

Te comparto el código para que lo analices.
Básicamente lo que hace el método split() es crear una lista donde cada elemento es una palabra. Por eso en el for se recorre cada nombre completo y en el mismo se hace un split creando la siguiente lista (ejemplo del primer elemento de estudiantes): ['Mario', 'Miguel', 'Diaz'] y dentro del for agregamos con el método append() a el elemento [0] de dicha lista, es decir 'Mario'. Y así consecutivamente se hace con cada elemento de estudiantes.
Saludos.

```
def main():
estudiantes= ['Mario Miguel Diaz', 'Luis Javier Alvarado', 'Juan de Cárdenas', 'Pedro Jesus Hernandez', 'Jose de Miranda', 'Juan de Salcedo'] # Full names
nombres = []  

for name in estudiantes:
    nombres.append(name.split()[0])

print(nombres)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Explica como funciona el código, para que el OP aprenda.